# Drupal 7 Batch Question

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I'm trying to set up a batch process and from the examples I see:

```
$context['results']['processed']++;
$context['message']
```

Is there a list of these, 'buckets' somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array keys available in `$context` are listed in [Batch operations](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/batch/7):

> - The following keys are provided:
>
>   - 'results' (read/write): The array of results gathered so far by the batch processing, for the current operation to append its own.
>   - 'message' (write): A text message displayed in the progress page.
> - The following keys allow for multi-step operations:
>
>   - 'sandbox' (read/write): An array that can be freely used to store persistent data between iterations. It is recommended to use this instead of $_SESSION, which is unsafe if the user continues browsing in a separate window while the batch is processing.
>   - 'finished' (write): A float number between 0 and 1 informing the processing engine of the completion level for the operation.
>       1 (or no value explicitly set) means the operation is finished and the batch processing can continue to the next operation.

Comment: Thank you, I googled but for some reason did not come to this page.